# Byte to PDF doesn't work. Only appears blank

Tags: javascript, pdf, byte

Good day everyone,

I'm trying to convert my `byte` from my api to `pdf` and open a javascript `window.open` but it shows a blank window.

Here's my sample code

```
...
console.log(response.data) // shows byte array properly from my api

window.open("data:application/pdf;base64; " + response.data, '', "height=600, width=800");     
...
```

I'm able to get my byte from api but the problem is, it doesn't show in my `window.open`. I even already tested the byte and send it to email on my backend, the pdf works fine and not blank.

I don't know why it doesn't show any result in my client side. I'm using Google Chrome anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try convert your byte array to base64 encoding like this:

```
window.open("data:application/pdf;base64; " + System.Convert.ToBase64String(response.data), '', "height=600, width=800");
```

Comment: `System.Convert.ToBase64String` is from `C#` right? it won't work in javascript